# io redirection to "cross" 2 programs

Tags: io-redirection

How to "cross" `stdin` and `stdout` of two programs? Specifically, I have 2 programs call `pgm1` and `pgm2`, they are interactive tic-tac-toe games. They both output a number (0to8) indicating position where it wants to mark and expect another number (0to8) indicating where the user wants to mark. The difference between the two is `pgm1` makes first move and `pgm2` makes second move. They both work fine via interactive user. Can they be made to play against each other using io redirection?

I tried the following things in vain:

1. Open `pgm2` in a separate terminal (it waits for input), find it's pid. Then run `pgm1` in another terminal 
   `./pgm1 < /proc/pid_pgm2/fd/1 > /proc/pid_pgm2/fd/0`
2. Made 2 pipes using mkfifo, say `pipe1` and `pipe2` and ran the following in two different terminals:  `./pgm1 < pipe1 > pipe2`  and  `./pgm2 < pipe2 > pipe1`
3. tried the above two, running pgm1 before pgm2, running pgm2 before pgm1
   I made sure to use `fflush(stdout)` in both the programs, immediately after using `printf()`.

Could anyone tell me what i am missing / or going wrong / or is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get this to work with a FIFO and a pipe.

```
$ mkfifo fifo
$ ./pgm2 < fifo | ./pgm1 > fifo
```

Program two's input is the fifo, and outputs to the pipe. Program one's input is the pipe and outputs to the fifo.

Be warned though: this is very racy in general, and can deadlock if the "ping/pong" between the processes isn't perfect.

See also this Stack Overflow question: [How to redirect stdout of 2nd process back to stdin of 1st process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129276/how-to-redirect-stdout-of-2nd-process-back-to-stdin-of-1st-process)

Comment: Thanks it is working... Just to know, is this not equivalent to the 2nd point that i tried? why is this working while that isn't?

Answer (score 2):

You've got a deadlock in your: `./pgm1 < pipe1 > pipe2` and `./pgm2 < pipe2 > pipe1`

The `open("pipe1", O_RDONLY)` done by the shell prior to executing `pgm1` will block until something else does a writing `open` on that same pipe. Until that's done, it won't do the next `open("pipe2", O_WRONLY)`.

Same for the other one. The `open("pipe2", O_RDONLY)` will block and because the `open("pipe2", O_WRONLY)` will not be done since the other shell is waiting for a writer on `pipe1`, you've got a deadlock.

Had you written it

```
pgm1 < pipe1 > pipe2 & pgm2 > pipe1 < pipe2
```

It would have worked.

On Linux, you can also write it:

```
{ pgm1 <&3 3<&- | pgm2 3<&-; } 3< /dev/fd/1 | :
```